# What is difference between declare method in lifecycle hook vs methods property in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am concerning about the way we declare a method in VueJs. Basically I am learning VueJs and while reading [this docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), specifically understanding the example. I realized that there is another way we can declare a method in Vue instance. Like the piece of code below:

```
watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
      this.debouncedGetAnswer()
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    // _.debounce is a function provided by lodash to limit how
    // often a particularly expensive operation can be run.
    // In this case, we want to limit how often we access
    // yesno.wtf/api, waiting until the user has completely
    // finished typing before making the ajax request. To learn
    // more about the _.debounce function (and its cousin
    // _.throttle), visit: https://lodash.com/docs#debounce
    this.debouncedGetAnswer = _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)
  }
```

The **debouncedGetAnswer** method make me confused.

So as what I have seen we can declare method in **created** lifecycle hook and use it later on(in this case is in watch functionality). 
So what are differences between declare methods in **methods property** and **lifecycle hook** such as created or mounted, whether former is public(mean we can use in template) and later is private(mean we only use in lifecycle hook) respectively?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no major differences in the end. The end result is the same, a function is attached to the vue instance, it can be called in the template or in the component js. There are subtle differences, such as functions declared in `methods` have their `this` value auto bound to the vue instance.

Comment: thank you @EricGuan, do you know any resources which mentioned about this?